# Cannot access SystemListView contents using Managed Win32 API's

Tags: c#, listview, screen-scraping, winapi

I am using the ManagedWindows API in a C# environment:
http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/

In the past I have successfully scraped the contents of listbox-like parts of other running programs using the code below, where I iterate through key/value pairs to find the list items. For this particular list of items, however, I can get an accurate number of items, but the value is always null!

Using this:

```
TargetMidWindow.Content.ComponentType
```

I have discovered that the list I am having issues with is a 'listview' whereas the other windows I have had success with are 'detailslistview' in case it matters. Below is the code I have for finding the data I want, which is almost identical to my other successful code with the exception of altering the search terms I used. Also, in case its relevant, the program I'm trying to pull data out of is MetaTrader4, and I've been able to scrape data off other parts of the program successfully.

```
    // Find the main window
        SystemWindow[] TopLevel = SystemWindow.AllToplevelWindows;
        SystemWindow TargetTopWindow = SystemWindow.ForegroundWindow;
        foreach (SystemWindow SearchWindow in TopLevel)
        {
            string Title = SearchWindow.Title;
            if (Title.Contains("MetaTrader"))
            {
                TargetTopWindow = SearchWindow;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Find the section where positions are contained
        SystemWindow[] MidLevel = TargetTopWindow.AllDescendantWindows;
        SystemWindow TargetMidWindow = SystemWindow.ForegroundWindow;
        foreach (SystemWindow SearchWindow in MidLevel)
        {
            string ClassName = SearchWindow.ClassName;
            if (ClassName.Contains("SysListView32"))
            {
                SystemWindow ParentWindow = SearchWindow.Parent;
                    if ((ParentWindow.Title.Contains("Terminal")))
                    {
                        TargetMidWindow = SearchWindow;

                    }
            }
        }

        // Get the positions
        Dictionary<string, string> RawValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> KVP in TargetMidWindow.Content.PropertyList)
        {
            string key = KVP.Key;
            string value = KVP.Value;
        }
```

Is there something special I need to do so that I do not get 'null' values for each list item?

Thanks!
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmya, wrapping Windows messages with a friendly API isn't that difficult.  Windows Forms would be a good example.  But that has a knack for running into a very solid wall once you start doing this with another process.

The specific message you need in order to read ListView items is LVM_GETITEM.  That's one of those solid wall messages.  The LPARAM argument you pass to SendMessage() needs to be a pointer to an LVITEM structure.  The control fills in the fields in that structure.  Problem is, the pointer you pass is only valid in *your* process, not the process who owns that window.

Fixing this takes a great deal of hackery.  You have to allocate memory that's valid inside that process.  That takes VirtualAllocEx() and ReadProcessMemory().  Plus all the glue calls you need to make these work.  I assume that this library you are using is *not* taking care of this.  Easy to find out, grep the source code files for these API function names.

Comment: Aw man, I was hoping it wouldn't take epic hackery. After farting around with it for a while more, it looks like I must take your approach if I'm committed to doing things this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the correct handle to a particular SysListView32 window, you need to start with the right window hierarchy. From the code snippet, it doesn't appear that you're actually finding the correct handle to retrieve a quote from the SysListView32 window. This is why you're receiving null values back. You would do well to run spy++ and determine the correct windows structure of the Metatrader terminal for your specific broker and build. I've found that the classes are different between builds for some of the windows, and also between some brokers, though to a lesser extent.

You're looking for the specific quote window hierarchy like this:

```
Metatrader -> Market Watch -> Market Watch -> SysListView32
```

By contrast, currently you're looking here in your code:

```
Metatrader -> Terminal -> (many sub-windows with SysListView32 class)
```

Where each level to the right is a child window of the window to the left.

Find the parent "Metatrader" window then chain down looking for the child window until you get to SysListView32. If you use spy++ you can read the class for the SysListView32 parent window (market watch), and use that to enumerate the windows to find the correct SysListView32 window. FYI the correct Market Watch class name for build 419 is:

```
Afx:00400000:b:00010003:00000000:00000000
```

Once you find the correct window, you may be able to extract its contents using your current component. I haven't tried that and am looking to port some code from VB6 from a ListView module that does in fact involve epic hackery. ;) I may take a look at the .NET Managed Windows API to see if this can help make the process simpler.

But in the mean time, if you do have to go low-level, the following VB6 source should help you get an idea of what is involved. This is fairly advanced material so good luck!

```
Public Function GetListviewItem(ByVal hWindow As Long, ByVal pColumn As Long, ByVal pRow As Long) As String
Dim result              As Long
Dim myItem              As LV_ITEMA
Dim pHandle             As Long
Dim pStrBufferMemory    As Long
Dim pMyItemMemory       As Long
Dim strBuffer()         As Byte
Dim index               As Long
Dim tmpString           As String
Dim strLength           As Long

Dim ProcessID As Long, ThreadID As Long
ThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, ProcessID)
'**********************
'init the string buffer
'**********************
ReDim strBuffer(MAX_LVMSTRING)

'***********************************************************
'open a handle to the process and allocate the string buffer
'***********************************************************
pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION Or PROCESS_VM_READ Or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, ProcessID)
pStrBufferMemory = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, 0, MAX_LVMSTRING, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)

'************************************************************************************
'initialize the local LV_ITEM structure
'The myItem.iSubItem member is set to the index of the column that is being retrieved
'************************************************************************************
myItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT
myItem.iSubItem = pColumn
myItem.pszText = pStrBufferMemory
myItem.cchTextMax = MAX_LVMSTRING

'**********************************************************
'write the structure into the remote process's memory space
'**********************************************************
pMyItemMemory = VirtualAllocEx(pHandle, 0, Len(myItem), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
result = WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, pMyItemMemory, myItem, Len(myItem), 0)

'*************************************************************
'send the get the item message and write back the memory space
'*************************************************************
result = SendMessage(hWindow, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, pRow, ByVal pMyItemMemory)
result = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, pStrBufferMemory, strBuffer(0), MAX_LVMSTRING, 0)
result = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, pMyItemMemory, myItem, Len(myItem), 0)

'**************************************************
'turn the byte array into a string and send it back
'**************************************************
For index = LBound(strBuffer) To UBound(strBuffer)
    If Chr(strBuffer(index)) = vbNullChar Then Exit For
    tmpString = tmpString & Chr(strBuffer(index))
Next index

tmpString = Trim(tmpString)

'**************************************************
'deallocate the memory and close the process handle
'**************************************************
result = VirtualFreeEx(pHandle, pStrBufferMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE)
result = VirtualFreeEx(pHandle, pMyItemMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE)

result = CloseHandle(pHandle)

If Len(tmpString) > 0 Then GetListviewItem = tmpString

End Function
```